# Adjusting views breadcrumb behavior with default contextual filter present?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that displays news articles by year, with the year given as a contextual filter received via the URL.

When no argument is present, I have views set a default argument of todays date, so it will show all of the news articles for 2013 when someone goes to /news. If they go to /news/2012, it would display the 2012 articles.

I've noticed that views is setting the breadcrumb to include "News" and the path to the main view **when no argument is present**, AKA going to /news. Based on the URL path, it doesn't make sense to display a breadcrumb to the main news page. I can sort of understand why this happens. Since I'm essentially telling views that there IS an argument, it doesn't know that it shouldn't display a breadcrumb.

What is the best approach to handle this situation? I'd like the breadcrumb to appear only when the contextual filter is present. If I could just disable breadcrumb handling completely, I suppose I could use another module to set the breadcrumb manually based on how I want it.